# Checking if there is internet connection webView did not appear

Tags: ios, uiwebview, reachability

I'm wondering why I don't get alert when I disconnect my internet connection. When I'm connected everything is going great, but when there is no connection, simply nothing appears, I'm pretty new in objective-c but I think this code looks correct.

Thanks for help anyway.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    webView.hidden = YES;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://url"];
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestURL];
    if ([[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.readyState"] isEqualToString:@"complete"]) {
        webView.hidden = NO;
    }
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection!"
                                                    message:@"Can't connect. Please check your internet Connection"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show]; }


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: If you want to check the connectivity with internet then you have to check it in your code. For this you can go through Apple's Reachbility code - https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: The thing is `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` is fired after the network operation , if there is any error. Since you don't have internet connection it probably skips it. `Reachability` is the way to go (before you do `loadRequest:`) as stated above. Good luck.

Comment: I couldn't be sure and double checked this. There is something else is wrong, your code shows the alert view on my end.

Comment: finally i used, webView.delegate=self; and it worked but, i get warning, and i want that to be correctly, Assigning to 'id<UIWebViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ncViewController *const __strong'

Comment: Make sure your view controllers header conforms the web view delegate to silence the warning. Like this: `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the connectivity with internet then you have to check it in your code. For this you can go through Apple's [Reachbility](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) code.

The method `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` will called if page could not be loaded due to some reason. This means it's not connectivity issue, this may be due to some internal errors at server.